# No output for existing permissions on non-IBMid users?

Tags: python-3.x, permissions, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I tried the example user permissions script at https://softlayer.github.io/python/set_permission/

It successfully lists existing user permissions for users with IBMids, but if I try a user without an IBMid, for example the account owner, or the brand master account, I get no output for existing permissions.  Is this expected?

The specific section of code in the example script that lists permissions is:

```
def main(self, user_id):
    permissions = self.client['User_Customer'].getPermissions(id=user_id)
    print("=== OLD PERMISSIONS ===")
    self.printPermissions(permissions)
    #setperm = {'keyName': "TICKET_ADD"}
    #self.client['User_Customer'].addPortalPermission(setperm, id=user_id)
    #permissions = self.client['User_Customer'].getPermissions(id=user_id)
    #print("=== NEW PERMISSIONS ===")
    #self.printPermissions(permissions)
```

I'm specifically interested in the old (existing) permissions part.  I have opened a ticket about this internally (ticket 57783823), and the recommendation was to come here first.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected to get empty response when you trying to get permission of master and brand account, because it is by design.

To get all users into the account and their permissions use the following rest, with this rest, you will get all users, their child’s and the permissions.

Method: 
GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers?objectMask=mask[id,parentId,firstName,lastName,permissions,childUsers]
```

finally, to get all available permissions you can use the following rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission/getAllObjects
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is the empty response when requesting permissions of master and brand accounts documented somewhere?  And is this is the best way to determine whether a user is a master user?  And would you be able to speak to why it was designed this way?

Comment: It will be empty because you can not see the permissions of the master account. It is at a higher level, you could only see the permissions with the master's credentials.

Comment: You can see in this link: you will retrieve a portal user’s permissions https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/getPermissions/